# PostgreSQL: Update my user table via Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, runtime-error

In PostgreSQL `user` is a reserved keyword that is used in an internal table, however I also have a separate `user` table in my own database that I need to use. Whenever I try to execute INSERT or UPDATE statements on the table, it generates the following error: `The column name 'id' was not found in this ResultSet`.

This is the Java code I am currently using:

```
PreparedStatement stat1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM user;");
PreparedStatement stat2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user SET date_created = ? , last_updated = ? , uuid = ? WHERE id = ?;");
ResultSet rs = stat1.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String tempId = uuid.toString();

    stat2.setTimestamp(1, curDate);
    stat2.setTimestamp(2, curDate);
    stat2.setString(3, tempId);
    stat2.setLong(4,rs.getLong("id"));

    stat2.executeUpdate();
}
```

So my question is, how could I insert or update the values in my personal `user` table without interfering with the keyword restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the table name like this

```
select * from "user";
```

Comment: thanks @Funtik , now i understand just simple way to escape characters in java.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
prepareStatement("UPDATE \"user\" set date_created = ?")
```

Or, better yet, rename your `user` table to something else, like `users`:

```
ALTER TABLE "user" RENAME TO users;
```